# warning sqrt: called with negative argument in gnu awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, awk

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation of all columns available in the following file.

Inputfile:

```
2017  04 15 00 00 00    36.606  -97.488  316.200      233.230  0.10      950.840  0.40
2017  04 15 00 00 01    36.606  -97.488  316.200      245.220  0.10      911.540  0.40
2017  04 15 00 00 02    36.606  -97.488  316.200      246.460  0.10      958.790  0.40
2017  04 15 00 00 03    36.606  -97.488  316.200      216.880  0.10      902.750  0.40
2017  04 15 00 00 04    36.606  -97.488  316.200      213.280  0.10      854.170  0.40
2017  04 15 00 00 05    36.606  -97.488  316.200      200.360  0.10      879.040  0.40
2017  04 15 00 00 06    36.606  -97.488  316.200      204.250  0.10      951.800  0.40
2017  04 15 00 00 07    36.606  -97.488  316.200      224.270  0.10     1015.570  0.40
2017  04 15 00 00 08    36.606  -97.488  316.200      203.490  0.10      849.640  0.40
2017  04 15 00 00 09    36.606  -97.488  316.200      198.620  0.10      969.190  0.40
2017  04 15 00 00 10    36.606  -97.488  316.200      213.530  0.10      896.930  0.40
2017  04 15 00 00 10    36.606  -97.488  316.200      216.300  0.10     1005.490  0.40
```

I am calculating the standard deviation of all column using following line:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[i]+=$i; s[i]+=$i*$i}}END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print sqrt(s[i]/NR-(a[i]/NR)^2)}}' infile > outfile
```

This calculates the standard deviation of all columns as per my requirement.
But when I used gnu awk (gawk) instead of awk this calculates the same but with the following warning:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=infile FNR=3600) warning: sqrt: called with a negative argument -5.63438e-15
```

I am unable to understand that what is the difference between awk and gawk gives me this warning.

Thank you

Comment: `awk` doesn't have imaginary numbers, so it can't get the square root of a negative number. The difference is that `gawk` warns about it, `awk` is silent.

Comment: What seems to be happening is that roundoff error is causing you to get a very tiny negative number. You should check for this and replace it with `0`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I have thousand files with millions lines in each. These are all real data and it does not have any negative values except column 8 (as shown in above file).  Because we are only considering those data which have values >=0. Now can this warning make an issue? Can we run the same line by ignoring the warning?

Comment: As @Barmar suggests, calculate the `variance` (before taking a square root
of it) and if the `variance` has a negative value, force it to be zero.
Please take a look of [here](https://accu.org/index.php/articles/1558)
for the study of rounding errors.

Comment: Thank you @tshiono, as I mentioned in the previous comment that we are avoiding negative values by considering column values >=0 (except for column 8).

Comment: Apparently you don't understand rounding issues, and fail to see that `-5.63438e-15` is in fact a negative number (small, but negative).  Both `gawk` and `mawk` are giving you a `-nan` for those rows, `gawk` explains to you **why** ...

Comment: Thank you @tink. It is interesting and I mentioned in my question too that both gawk and mawk are not providing me a -nan values for associated negative values but even I am getting correct values with the warning.

Comment: That's quite bizarre, then, because with the little snippet of data provided and your code snippet I get nan from both gawk and mawk for lines 7 & 8 ...

Comment: You mean to say column 7 & 8? Actually I have file size in tons of Gbs there I can not keep entire file here. But I tried in my system and our cluster at my organization and both have me same and correct response both for gawk and mawk. No one gave me -nan for the associated negative values. This is really interesting and shocking as well.

Comment: No, not column, row. And now I wonder about your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the variance (square of standard deviation) of input data
is calculated with the following equation:

[image]

The problem here is the mean (x-bar) value cannot be determined *until* all data
are read. Therefore the equation above is supposed not to be suitable for
an actual implementation.
In practice the equation is transformed as:

[image]

which is suitable for data-by-data calculation.

Although those equations are *theoretically equivalent*, the second one
may produce a negative value due to round-off errors. It may occur if all the data are identical (*regardless of the value itself*).

A possible workaround is set the variance to zero for the negative value
as I've noted in the comment.
Another workaround is go back to the original definition with:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        sum[i]+=$i
    next
}
# following lines are executed in the 2nd iteration
FNR==1 {
    n=NR-1
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        mean[i]=sum[i]/n
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        sum2[i]+=($i-mean[i])*($i-mean[i])
}
END {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        print sqrt(sum2[i]/n)
}' infile infile > outfile
```

which is less efficient as it reads the data twice.